# MarkerWithLabel Not printing correctly

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have put some MarkerWithLabel On my map. They all are working fine but when I print the map they become transparent.

[image: Map I Browser]

Pdf Image file

[image: PDF file image]

My marker are becoming transparent
here are my css and marker

```
var marker1 = new MarkerWithLabel({
                position: Location,
                draggable: false,
                raiseOnDrag: true,
                map: map,
                labelContent: ' Text ',
                labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(22, 0),
                labelClass: "labels", // the CSS class for the label
                labelStyle: { opacity: 0.99 },
                icon: {}
            });

       .labels 
        {
            color: black;
            background-color: white;
            font-family: "Lucida Grande" , "Arial" , sans-serif;
            font-size: 15px;
            font-weight: bold;
            text-align: center;
            font-style:normal;
            border: 1px solid grey;
            white-space: nowrap;
            border-radius:3px;

        }
```

Comment: what happens if you change the opacity from 0.99 to 1?

Comment: Nothing happens. still it shows same problem

Comment: this may be a printer-specific behaviour, there usually is an option "print backgrounds", maybe it helps when you toggle this option.

Comment: You can set different style rules for reading (screen) and for printing using `@media print {...}`. See article [How To Set Up A Print Style Sheet](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/24/how-to-set-up-a-print-style-sheet/)

Comment: Thanks @AntoJurkovic I have already set up my page. But facing issue only on markup transparency.